# Form without <form> tag

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I've got a moderation form in the admin section, where a moderator can edit the text, the user has written.

Here is my form:

```
function phase2_moderation_form($admin, $moderation, $phase2, $edit, $sdid) {

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM {phase2_submitted_data} WHERE sdid = :sdid';
    $results = db_query($sql, array(':sdid' => $sdid));
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $submission[] = $result;
    }

    $form = array(); 

    $form['status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Status'),
    '#options' => array(
            '0' => t('not enabled'),
            '1' => t('enabled')
            ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#value' => $submission[0]->status,
    );

    $form['question'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => t('question'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#value' => $submission[0]->question,
    );

    $form['topic'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('topic'),
            '#options' => array(
                    'social' => t('Social'),
                    'culture' => t('Culture'),
                    'government' => t('Government'),
                    'environment' => t('Environment'),
                    'traffic' => t('Traffic'),
                    'other' => t('Other')
                    ),
            '#default_value' => 'other',
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#attributes' => array('id' => array('topic'), 'name' => array('topic')),
            '#title_display' => 'before',
            '#value' => $submission[0]->topic,
            );
    $form['answer'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => t('Our Answer'),
            '#required' => FALSE,
            '#value' => $submission[0]->answer,
            '#title_display' => 'before',
            );
    $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
            );
    $form['#submit'][0] = 'phase2_moderation_edit_form_submit';
    $form['cancel'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => t('Cancel'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Actually nothing special, but there is no form-tag rendered.

In Firebug, I see that there are the form-element-divs, but there is no  around that divs. 
I already tried to comment out the Cancel-Button, but that doesn't help.

Could you please help me?

Here is the hook_menu:

```
function phase2_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/moderation/phase2/edit/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('Moderation Phase 2'),
        'page callback' => 'phase2_moderation_form',
        'page arguments' => array(0,1,2,3,4),
        'access arguments' => array('moderation phase 2'),
        'file' => 'phase2.moderation.form.inc',
    );
 return $items;
}
```

I do not call anything extra (no preprocess-function or tpl.php) or anything else.
I thought Drupal render it itself by a function deep inside.

Bye Tom

Comment: Have you tried it with standard theme like Bartik?

Comment: How do you render that form?, my guess is that the form's children (hidden fields) are missing also..

Comment: @Molot: It is the seven theme, I use in this case

Comment: @PanChrono: I do not render the form explicitly. Where (in which function) do I have to say drupal_get_form()?

Comment: Please show us code you use to render it. We can't quite tell where in it you should call certain functions if we can't see it in the first place.

Comment: @Molot: I have no code, where I render the form... this is probably the problem, but where do I have to render the form?
What's interesting: I see the form as expected, but there's only no form-tag around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `'drupal_get_form'` as a `page callback` and use `array('phase2_moderation_form', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` as `page arguments`

Or you can change the `page callback` to another function, like for example `'phase2_get_my_form'` and in that function call `return drupal_get_form('phase2_moderation_form', $arg0, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4);` (obviously change the `$argX` to your proper argument names.)

Comment: aahh, coooool :) now, there is the form, but my sql-statement doesn't work. I think I try you second version and try to query the db in the other function. Thank you @Beebee

Comment: You should be able to query the database from any function, there are no restrictions as far as I know, except for when drupal is not yet bootstrapped, but that shouldn't happen in your case. Please double check your code or even better, strip it down to its absolute basics (make a backup of your current code first!), and go from there.